# Display CCSlider in two colour in cocos2d v3

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am new in Cocos2d iPhone Development. How to display a `CCSlider` in two different `UIImage` in cocos2d v3 .Like in cocos2d v2 `CCControlExtension/CCControlSlider` class has a method below here we can put two different images "`bgFile`" and "`progressFile`" for empty bar and fill bar.

cocos2d v2:-

```
+ (id)sliderWithBackgroundFile:(NSString *)bgFile progressFile:(NSString *)progressFile thumbFile:(NSString *)thumbFile;
```

My Question is How we can diffentiate two different image for empty bar and full bar in `CCSlider` native class of cocos2d v3 the method is below:

cocos2d v3:-

```
- (id) initWithBackground:(CCSpriteFrame*)background andHandleImage:(CCSpriteFrame*)handle;
```

Thank You...

Comment: @NieshPatil : ahhh, now i get your question. Unfortunately the progress and background sprites have disappeared from CCSlider in cocos2d v3. If you really need it, i guess you will have no choice but to create your own 'extended' slider.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg do you have any sample code for 'extended' slider?

Comment: unfortunately not, CCSlider is just about the only CCControl that I am able to use 'as is' ... i have extended every other ones for my specifics. It is not that hard :) the object model is good and easy to follow/extend.